# C++ Polymorphism : Is it possible to use a function from a double derived class into the base class?

Tags: c++

I'm new to polymorphism and I'm trying to learn how this exactly works .
I want for example to get the print() function of class Y and use it in the base class .
Is this possible to do ?

```
class A
{
public:
  A() = default;
  virtual void print()
  {
    //Is it possible to get the print() function of class Y here ?
  };
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  B() = default;
  void print(){ std::cout << "B " << std::endl;}
};

class C : public A
{
  public:
  C() = default;
  void print(){ std::cout << "C " << std::endl;}
};

class Y : public C , public B 
{
  public:
  Y() = default;
  void print()
  {
     B::print();
     C::print();
  }
 
};

int main()
{ 
  A a;
  a.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about what you want, You already can do: `Y y; A& a = y; a.print(); /* output: B C */`.

Comment: You're (almost) doing a [diamond pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) which should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main()` is creating an `A` object directly, not a `Y` object. That is why you are not seeing the output you want. Polymorphism only works when accessing derived class objects via base class pointers/references, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{ 
  Y y;
  A *a = static_cast<C*>(&y);
  a->print();
  return 0;
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{ 
  Y y;
  A &a = static_cast<C&>(y);
  a.print();
  return 0;
}
```

The reason for the type cast is because`Y` has 2 `A` portions, one from `B` and one from `C`, so you have to help the compiler a little by specifying which `A` you want to point to.